# adding total in button

Tags: java, vector, controller, software-design

i have some problems adding codes in the button so example : i key in  2 on quantity it will * the price and quantity example 400 * 2 = 800 but when i key in 2 again means 800 x 2 = 1600, can anyone guide me? thanks the errors are shown in the last 2 line.
` private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());

```
        purchasecontroller.PurchaseProduct(id, qty);
       String getname = displaycontroller.SearchbyProductName(id);
        jLabel4.setText( "" + getname );
        jLabel3.setText("" + qty);
          jList1.addElement(getname + qty);
  //     jList1.add(new Product("Hello", 1));
        String getprice = displaycontroller.SearchbyProductPrice(id);
      int total = qty * Integer.parseInt (getprice);
      jLabel11.setText("" + total );
       int finals = (total * qty);
       jLabel12.setText("" + finals );
}
```

`

Comment: What kind of problems do you have?

Comment: What do you think it means to multiply a string by an integer? Hint: you're already doing the right thing (well, at least something approaching the right thing) for `qty`...

Comment: adding the * so it will keep on adding the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
int total = qty * Integer.parseInt (getprice);
```

instead of

```
int total = qty * getprice;
```

Comment: i having one more problem how to i add + the total, for example 400 * 2 = 800, den i key in 3 in the quantity it should display all total like 3 x 800 = 2400 + 800 = 3200

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
int total = qty * getprice;
```

You're trying to multiply an int (qty) by a String (getprice), which can't be done.

You need to parse getprice as an integer, and then subsitute that new integer for getprice in the `total` assignment.